# how to split a string with javascript - Separate first name and surname from textbox

Tags: javascript, string, function, split

I'm using the following code to split up surname from first + middle names and place them in three seperate fields. One holds the surname, one holds the firstnames and one holds all of them but re-arranged as lastname, firstname(s)

```
function switchName(ele){
        var splitName = ele.value.split(" ");
        var surname = splitName[splitName.length-1]; //The last one
        var firstnames 
        for (var i=0; i < splitName.length-1; i++){
                firstnames += splitName[i] + " "
                }

    document.getElementById("hdnSNFNS").value = surname + ", " + firstnames;
    document.getElementById("hdnEmployeeSurname").value = surname;
    document.getElementById("hdnEmployeeFirst").value = firstnames;
```

It works as is but I get this output for the firstnames

> Stone, undefinedJoss Helen

I've played around with it for ages but cant stumble across the correct solution.

Comment: Such distinctions may not always work - not all cultures use such forms. Even simple cases like _John von Neumann_ may trip you up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function switchName(ele){
    var splitName = ele.value.split(" ");
    var surname = splitName[splitName.length-1]; //The last one
    var firstnames = ""; // <- forgot to initialize to an empty string
    for (var i=0; i < splitName.length-1; i++){
        firstnames += splitName[i] + " "
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Raynos, i'm bit of a newbie but presumed it would be something simple.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `;` on the 4th line line and you should initialize `firstnames` to an empty string.

`var firstnames = "";`.

Right now, the first iteration of your loop concatenates the first name to an uninitialized variable and that's where the `undefined` comes from. With the initialization you'll concatenate with "nothing" and it will produce the expected result.